# multiple textbox validation using either javascript or angular 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have three textboxes and a submit button. Need to enable submit button only when there is text in any of the 3 textboxes or else the button needs to be disbaled. What would be the code in angular1 or javascript to achieve this validation? Below is my code

```
First name:
<br>
<input type="text" id="textsend1" name="firstname1" value="Mickey">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="textsend2" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="textsend3" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled>
```

Comment: Why do two of the textboxes have the same `name`?

Comment: good catch. Changed the name. But its still not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a class to enable or disable de button, check this [url](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) or just use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: I can disbale button using  ng-diabled . But how to enable the button again when there is a text in the textbox. What would be the logic for that ?

Comment: use a expresion, an if cause, see the example at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Tried using that link but  It was not helpful for multiple textbox validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form and `ng-required` to accomplish this. With 3 textboxes it's manageable, but if you start to get more it can get a bit messy.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = '';
    $scope.middlename = '';
    $scope.lastname = '';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" 
           name="firstname" 
           ng-model="firstname" 
           ng-required="!middlename && !lastname"><br>     
    Middle name:<br>
    <input type="text" 
           name="middlename" 
           ng-model="middlename" 
           ng-required="!firstname && !lastname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" 
           name="lastname" 
           ng-model="lastname" 
           ng-required="!firstname && !middlename"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" 
           value="Submit" 
           ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
  </form>
</div>
```